# Passwordless sign-in/sign-up with phone number

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sms, asp.net-identity

Good Evening.

I'm programming a backend containing an HTTP API that allows the client to login or register through a provided phone number. Because of this, this process is quite different from traditional authentication flow.

Because phone number oriented authentication is not secure (but extremely convenient), you can't allow a user to login into someone else account solely using phone number, which was a common case that can happen in phone number recycling cases ([example is Lyft](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/02/when-phone-verification-and-recycled-numbers-collide-lyft-leaks-user-data/)).

That's why i thought to emulate just a part of how Lyft currently handle with this, by requiring the user to specify his email during registration and account recovery (i guess login is made with an additional magic string from the smartphone).

In my Web API, for the sign in process, the user sends the following data: phone number, smartphone id, and sms verification id and code.
That's when the business rules for authentication take an important role:

- If the smartphone id doesn't correspond with the phone number stored in the database (maybe the phone was changed or reset), the server assumes that the number is already owned by another user and responds with 409 (Conflict)
- If the number is not owned by anyone, the server responds with 403 (Forbidden), that means that you're free to register a new account with that number.
- The successful path is when the smartphone id corresponds with the phone number, two tokens are returned to the client (refresh and access tokens).

For registering (sign up) there's also a almost similar set of business rules, the registering process also requires the user email for later account confirmation (and invoices), this confirmation **effectively** associate the phone number and email with that client.

That same email can be later used to recover a account (if the user switched smartphone or number), thus preventing the common problem associated with phone number authentication.

I choose to decouple Identity from my domain model, which is named **PhoneNumberAuth** (i even created a bounded context).

I have a load of questions concerning this. ASP.NET Identity it's the common way to do authentication in standard ways (email, external, etc).

- Should i extend Identity classes to cover my custom business rules? If so, what's the best path?
- Should i instead create a façade classe to implement my business rules? Like i did here: https://gist.github.com/Henry-Keys/856bc84355b30c4095c88b8c28d547da

In one or another case, i will end up using Identity for **Authorization** (roles, claims, etc).
I just want help (or a guideline) to end up with the best solution.

[EDIT]
One thing that i want is to generate email confirmation token, Identity provides a easy way to generate and manage them. But it's difficult to integrate Identity with my custom authentication in order to achieve that.

Comment: fwiw: 403 for "you're free to register a new account with that number" is a heavy misuse of http status codes. 403 means the logged in user doesn't have the permission to access the resource. If the user is not logged in, 401 is returned.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion, i really appreciate.

Comment: That wasn't a suggestion to replace 403 with 401 though, as 401 says you are not logged in which is in appropriate during a login process (causes endless loop depending on the client => User not logged in? => Redirect to login page => User not logged in? => redirect to login page etc."